# Xamarin Forms - Bind UI controls to object properties (those objects are in a list)

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, dynamic-forms

In the codebehind I loop through a list that is defined in the viewmodel. For each item I check what type of Control (Entry, Picker etc..) I need to create. The problem is that I don't know how to bind those controls with properties from objects in the list defined in the viewmodel..

My code:

```
        // Create controls dynamically
        for (int i = 0; i < (BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems[i];

            var description = new Label()
            {
                Text = item.Description
            };
            stack.Children.Add(description);

            if ((item.ChecklistItemType == Domain.ChecklistItemType.Number))
            {
                var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;

                numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "item.Value"); // How should I do this??

                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
            }
            else if ((item.ChecklistItemType == Domain.ChecklistItemType.Email))
            {
                var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Email;
                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
            }
        }

        Content = stack;
```

How should I bind those UI controls with properties in the item object? (Ps: the item object is taken from a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `item` is unknown to your `numberEntry` object. You cannot expect `SetBinding` to magically know what you mean with `item` - could be anything. In order to make sense of `SetBinding`, the `BindingContext` of your control has to be set. In your case, it'd be sensible to set it to `item`

```cs
var numerEntry = new Entry();
numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;

numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, path: "Value");
numerEntry.BindingContext = item;

stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
```

Since the `path` parameter (written explicitly for clarification) indicates a path to a property *relative to the `BindingContext`*, the `"item.Value`" has to be changed to `"Value"`.

Comment: What about this:                     numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(mode: BindingMode.TwoWay, path: "Value", source: item));

Comment: I set the source instead of bindingcontext

Comment: @MYil Should be fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you loop item from List, and want to bind every item to UI, I do some code according to your code, you can take a look:

```
 public Page33()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new CheckListEditViewModel();

        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

        for(int i=0;i<(BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems.Count;i++)
        {
            var item = (BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems[i];

            var description = new Label()
            {
                Text = item.Description
            };
            stack.Children.Add(description);

            if ((item.ChecklistItemType == "Number"))
            {
                var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;

                numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("value",BindingMode.TwoWay,source:item));

                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
            }
            else if ((item.ChecklistItemType == "Email"))
            {
                var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Email;
                numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("value", BindingMode.TwoWay, source: item));
                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
            }
        }
        this.Content = stack;
    }
}

public class CheckListEditViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private List<EditModel> _CheckListItems;
    public List<EditModel> CheckListItems
    {
        get { return _CheckListItems; }
        set
        {
            _CheckListItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CheckListItems");
        }
    }
    public CheckListEditViewModel()
    {
        CheckListItems = new List<EditModel>();
        CheckListItems.Add(new EditModel() {Description="one model",ChecklistItemType="Email",value="123@outlook.com" });
        CheckListItems.Add(new EditModel() { Description = "two model", ChecklistItemType = "Number",value="12345" });
        CheckListItems.Add(new EditModel() { Description = "three model", ChecklistItemType = "Email",value="345@outlook.com" });
        CheckListItems.Add(new EditModel() { Description = "four model", ChecklistItemType = "Number",value="567" });
    }
}
public class EditModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ChecklistItemType { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I set current ContentPage BindingContext = new CheckListEditViewModel(), then loop every item from List, then the item is the source of current control.

[image]